# How to display list data on pop up using struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin, struts2-bootstrap-plugin

I have list of object in my action class as below.

```
private ArrayList<Employee> emp_list;
public ArrayList<Employee> getEmp_list() {
    return emp_list;
}
public void setEmp_list(ArrayList<Employee> emp_list) {
    this.emp_list = emp_list;
}
```

Bean Class : (it has getter and setters)

```
private String name;
private String designation;
private String project;
```

Now on jsp page I want display this list data to be displayed as **table on pop-up on same page** on button or href click(showing size of list).

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Modal Example</h2>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <table>
            <s:iterator value="emp_list">
                <tr>
                    <td><s:property value="name" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Display Details</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </table>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Employee Details</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Name</td>
                                <td><s:property value="name" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Designation</td>
                                <td><s:property value="designation" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Project</td>
                                <td><s:property value="project" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Please help me out I've stucked here.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. Isn't this simple jQuery or plugin usage?

Comment: What did you try? Is it something table on pop-up or popup on the same page?

Comment: yes Roman you are right, I need table on pop-up on same page but not aware how to implement it

Comment: But you didn't tell us where did you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`<s:iterator>`](https://struts.apache.org/docs/iterator.html) tag in your jsp
[here](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-iterator-tag-example/) you can find an example with struts2 iterator usage with a table.

For the pop-up part, you can use any Html/JS combo (if using bootstrap you can use a [`modal`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)) and just show or hide your code as needed

Comment: can you please give some sample using bootstrap

Comment: Well, use the same modal example link (the modal one I linked) and just replace it with the table content you need from the other links, the modal is always there in your jsp, it's just not showing until you show it with JS.